# Logging in with Google OpenID causes privacy issues on Stack Overflow (and others?) - it needs to change

Tags: support, login

I am new user of Stack Overflow. I noticed that at the top there is an icon for  "recent inbox messages" and another icon for "recent achievements".  I saw a long list of inbox messages, so I wanted to clear it out.

At the bottom of this list, I saw a link to "see all your inbox", and I clicked on it. I was hoping to see all my messages, and delete them or mark them as read. My click got me to a page where I was required to login with a 'Google or Yahoo or Facebook' OpenID account. So, I gave my Google account/password. The next page I saw said  "Stack Exchange would like to view your email address". I did not want to share my email address (and I can see a good number of people who are not willing to share their email address).

When I declined to share my address, I was kicked out, and I never got to the 'inbox' that I was trying to get to. How am I supposed to delete the messages and 'recent acheivements list', if  I can not login?

In my opinion, there should be a direct link to the inbox and 'recent acheivements list',  from my profile page on Stack Overflow. Please treat this as feature request. In the meantime, if there is another way to delete this inbox list (which would grow over time), please let me know.

Comment: If you are not willing to login, then... But while we're at it, you realize you are logged in, now?

Comment: I think it just means that stackoverflow will now your email address. If you have an account, they already do.

Comment: P.s. there are no inbox messages to clear out. It's there to stay.

Comment: Erm... how can one use OpenID *without* revealing one's email address? It's the key!

Comment: @Colin'tHart: use an OpenID provider that's not also your email provider.

Comment: @Wooble It's still *your* email address -- ie an email address that belongs to you. But, yes, you could use that and ignore its function.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: An OpenID provider doesn't need to run an SMTP server at all.

Comment: @nsamuel: Are you aware that your email address won't be publicly visible on the site? (StackOverflow will know it but not other users)

Comment: @Colin'tHart: No, the OpenID URL is the key. The OpenID provider *can* provide an email address too, but it is not required.

Comment: Aah, OK. I was under the mistaken impression that the email address was the key. It appears from the answer below that the SE uses the email address as the key, whereas I guess they could have used the OpenID URL?

Answer (score 8):

The global inbox is managed by stackexchange.com, because it regroups the inbox for all the sites for which you have an account. The Stack Exchange site is the "parent" of all the sites of the Stack Exchange network.

To access your profile on Stack Exchange, you need an account on the site. Since it's mandatory for each Stack Exchange account to have your email address, you need to allow the OpenID provider to share it with any stack-site you want access to.

Your email address is only used internally by Stack Exchange and is not public. It has been (still is?) part of the mechanism used to bind all your accounts together. It is not public information and no one except from the Stack Exchange team and moderators will have access to your email. By the way, since you already have an account on one Stack Exchange site, you already have disclosed it to them, so why not create your Stack Exchange profile? Besides, Stack Exchange provides its own OpenID services if you don't want to use a third party like Google, Yahoo, etc.

Also, the inbox is a collection of notifications. Messages can have two states: read or unread. There isn't any clearing option. The top bar icons will only show the most recent notifications, and turn to green whenever there is unread content. Clicking on the menu will show the notifications and turn any notification from unread to read.